# Why real part of fft converts image into rotation + original?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I have read this image:

[image]

taken its FFT (2D) and then Inverse FFT to get exactly the image back:

```
imfft = fft2(photographer);
im = uint8(ifft2(imfft));

imshow(im); %Output is same image
```

But when I change the fourier and take only the real part,

```
imfft = real(fft2(photographer));
im = uint8(ifft2(imfft));
imshow(im);
```

I get an image like this (*note that size change is irrelevant and only due to saving it from Matlab figure handler*):

[image]

Why does this happen?

**UPDATE**

As suggested, this question was posted on DSP StackExchange and got the answer [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30770/why-real-part-of-fft-converts-image-into-rotation-original)

Comment: the code you provided did not take the real part of the 2d-fft.

Comment: yes, this is the right expectation, simply because of how Fourier transform works - if you want the Math behind it, you can post this up on Stack Exchange Signal Proc. http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real part represents only symmetric basis vectors (cosine waves that are symmetric around the center of an FFT aperture).  So any IFFT reconstruction using only the real part (all imaginary components == 0) can only (re)produce images that are symmetric around the center (by distorting them per your example, for instance).

Comment: Is there any reference for this?

Comment: A Google search on FFT even/odd symmetry turns up lots of stuff, such as: https://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs530/symmetry.pdf and http://www.intmath.com/fourier-series/3-fourier-even-odd-functions.php

Comment: Thanks!! I just wanted to see Maths behind it, so was skeptical